# Question on the Sarason notes "New Hilbert spaces from old"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am stuck on something written on page 197 in the following notes,

https://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/sa91_Donald%20Sarason.pdf

It is in his argument why $U \vert_{H_{0}}$ is a pure isomerty. He motivates it by "because $H^{+}$ is the smallest $U$ invariant subspace containg $H$".

But $H^{+}_{0}$ does not cotain $H$ by definiton, so whats the reasoning here? Am I missing something or is there a missprint here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is that the dilation is assumed to be *minimal*, which as Sarason says means that "$U$ does not admit a decomposition into a direct sum of two unitary operators the first of which is also a dilation of $T$".

Since you have $H^+=H\oplus H_0^+$, if $H_0^+$ admits a subspace $K$ such that $UK=K$, we can write 
$$
H^+=H\oplus K^\perp\oplus K,
$$
and so $U=U|_{H\oplus K}\oplus U|_K$, contradicting the minimality.

Comment: Thats the drawback of "informal surverys", one might miss a defintion. On the other hand it give a great deal of intuition which formal presentations might fails to deliver. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes. I agree it is not particularly clear. On the other hand, I knew about Sz.Nagy's dilations from other sources, so looking at Sarason's view was nice.